# Condition based click event in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In my application I would like to have conditional based click event ,

```
<div class="trashIconDiv" (click)="if(idx > 0) {removeSelected(item.spId)}">
```

In the above code removeSelected function should be executed only when idx >0 , any idea how to implement

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
(click)="idx > 0 && removeSelected(item.spId)"
```

Comment: This is so simple! Combined it with 
```[ngClass]="{'icon-disabled': !isIconButtonActivated}"```

Comment: what about `else`?

Comment: @tatsu it is using a ternary operand, for this example you could do:
`(click)="idx > 0 ? removeSelected(item.spId) : somethingElse($event)`

Comment: What if I need to use an observable in the condition?

Comment: @IdanYadgar did you try to use the async pipe ?

Comment: word of warning this will prevent click events for children inside the element.

Answer (score 42):

Simply use a ternary:

```
<div class="trashIconDiv" (click)="idx > 0 ? removeSelected(item.spId) : false">
```

This will only call `removeSelected` function when the condition is true, if it's false then it won't do anything.

Comment: how to do this with multiple condtion. 
`<div class='class1' *ngIf='cndtn != "undefined"' 
          (click)='cndtn1 && cndtn2 then functionToCall()'>
          <ion-icon class='icon-location'></ion-icon>{{xxxx}}
          <ion-icon class='icon-arrow-right floatRight iconArrowRight'></ion-icon>
        </div>`

Comment: Use true as the false ternary condition result if you want the event to perform it's default operation. Eg if your event is (keydown) and you want all keys except TAB to not do default, then use (keydown)="$event.keyCode != 9 ? doOtherThing() : true" or doOtherThing() could just be false instead.

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde , how to do it with Multiple execution with single condition like this => (click)="condition && var1 = true; var2 = true;" 
In my case condition only works on first execution ie. var1 = true;

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with conditional in `(click)` because I combined it with the `async` pipe:

`(click)= flag$ | async ? handler() : false` ->
**Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression**

My solution was to move the `async` pipe one level above:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ value: flag$ | async } as myFlag">
   <button (click)="myFlag.value ? handler() : false">
   </button>
</ng-container>
```

Here ***ngIf** is used not to check a condition, but rather just to save observable value in an object, so the result can be used by `(click)`:

```
*ngIf="{ value: flag$ | async } as myFlag"
```