# How to call function on input text change in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-components

I want to call the type script function on input change of text box, and its working for me. But it call on every change, I want to call when the minimum number of character in the text box are 5.

```
export class StudentMaintenanceComponent implements OnInit {
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-student-management',
        template: `<input placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text" [maxlength]="5" (input)="SearchData($event.target.value)">`,
        styleUrls: ['./app-student-management.css']
    })

    SearchData(_no: string) { // should be called when minimum no of character are 5 in the text field.
        console.log(_no);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096161/condition-based-click-event-in-angular-2. I think this is the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

You can write something like this

```
(input)="$event.target.value.length > 5 && SearchData($event.target.value)"
```

You can also use template reference variable like this

```
<input placeholder="" #textInput class="form-control" type="text" [maxlength]="5" (input)="textInput.value.length > 5 && SearchData(textInput.value)">
```