# Creatin read mode for the app Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on creating the read mode for the whole application. Is there some best practices for such case? 
For now I am using the next idea:

`<div
    (click)="!readOnly ? a() : null">
</div>`

Is it bad practice to set listeners to null of to fn with ternary operator in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as below as well

```
<div (click)="!readonly && a()">
```

to make it simpler.
Reference: [Condition based click event in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096161/condition-based-click-event-in-angular-2)

This is obviously better than setting listeners to null.
You can return `false` instead of setting `null` as per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096161/condition-based-click-event-in-angular-2/45096197#45096197)

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk you may mark it as answer if it helped so that other SO users understand this as a solution